# Transform values based on two sets of dates not in sequence

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have daily sales figures.

```
set.seed(24)
Values <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:200,70*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
Daily <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 700))
Sales <- cbind(Values,Daily)
colnames(Sales) <- c("values","daily")
```

I also have how much of the upcoming sales figures will be lost (from wages) and is projected three times a month (not at regular intervals). This is expressed as a percentage of the daily sales figure.

```
Three_month <- c('2014-01-01','2014-01-12','2014-01-21','2014-02-03','2014-02-11','2014-02-20', 
      '2014-03-04','2014-03-13','2014-03-20','2014-04-01','2014-04-11','2014-04-23',
      '2014-05-05','2014-05-12','2014-05-21','2014-06-03','2014-06-11','2014-06-20', 
      '2014-07-04','2014-07-13','2014-07-20','2014-08-01','2014-08-11','2014-08-23',
      '2014-09-05','2014-09-12','2014-09-21','2014-10-03','2014-10-11','2014-10-20', 
      '2014-11-04','2014-11-13','2014-11-20','2014-12-01','2014-12-11','2014-12-23', 
      '2015-01-05','2015-01-12','2015-01-21','2015-02-03','2015-02-11','2015-02-20', 
      '2015-03-04','2015-03-13','2015-03-20','2015-04-01','2015-04-11','2015-04-23',
      '2015-05-05','2015-05-12','2015-05-21','2015-06-03','2015-06-11','2015-06-20', 
      '2015-07-04','2015-07-13','2015-07-20','2015-08-01','2015-08-11','2015-08-23',
      '2015-09-05','2015-09-12','2015-09-21','2015-10-03','2015-10-11','2015-10-20', 
      '2015-11-04','2015-11-13','2015-11-20','2015-12-01','2015-12-11','2015-12-23')
Three_month <- as.data.frame(Three_month)
Three_month$Three_month <- as.Date(Three_month$Three_month)
Percentage <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:15,7.2*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
Losses <- cbind(Three_month,Percentage)
colnames(Losses) <- c("three_month","percentage")
```

**My question is how can I get projected daily sales whereby the percentage losses are added back on to the original values?** So for example, say the first two values if in the 'Losses' dataframe are 10% and 15%, how can I create a variable which calculates each 'value' + 10% of value from 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-11 and then each 'value' + 15% of value from 2014-01-12 to 2014-01-20 (and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
Sales$newcol<-Sales$values*
        (Losses$percentage[findInterval(Sales$daily,Losses$three_month)]/100+1)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much